# " Message: Security error." While Requesting a Https Uri using WebClient OR HttpWebRequest using SilverLight Client

Tags: rest, silverlight-4.0, https, webclient, cross-domain-policy

My Silverlight Client and REST Web Server(Implented using ASP.NET Handlers) both are on same domain.
Both HTTP and HTTPS protocol bindings are configured in IIS 7.0

When Request a URI using HTTPS , i Get Error " Message: "Security error."
But Same URI works just fine on HTTP request without any error

```
private void btnLoginWebRequest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


       bool httpResult = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
       bool httpsResult = WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);

      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
      {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["CustomHeader"] = String.Format("myHeaders={0}", "Value");
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@"https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/MyRESTApi/UserGroups"));
       });
    }
void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
    }
}
```

I Get a Error and e.Error contains the following Error information

```
{System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)}
    [System.Security.SecurityException]: {System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Security error."
    StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)"
```

crossdomain.xml is as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="true"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

clientaccesspolicy.xml is as follows :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <access-policy>
         <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
          <allow-from http-request-headers="*">      
            <domain uri="https://"/>
            <domain uri="http://"/>
          </allow-from>      
          <grant-to>      
            <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
          </grant-to>      
        </policy>
      </cross-domain-access>

</access-policy>
```

I Have seen many threads related to similar error on stack overflow but not able to resolve this issue by any of the solutions provided in those threads. Am i missing something?